# Sending chat in custom IRC client

Tags: java, sockets, chat, protocols, irc

I'm programming a custom IRC client in java, and I have the recieving messages in chat fine, but what I can't figure out is how to send chat messages. I looked at IRCHelp.org but I didn't really understand the section about "Message format in ‘pseudo’ BNF, " which I believe is the section I might be looking for.

1. Is this the section I'm looking for?
2. If not, what section should I look at?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think your best option might be to use an IRC library.
The IRC protocol is fairly simple but large at the same time, to write a complete library would actually be a fair bit of work. On the other hand it's easy to write it yourself since IRC is a text based protocol.

Why don't you take a look at one of these:

- [JerkLib](http://jerklib.sourceforge.net/) *- Uses NIO and is event driven*
- [Sorcix' sIRC](https://github.com/sorcix/sIRC/) *- Very compact library, uses listeners*
- [PircBot](http://www.jibble.org/pircbot.php) *- Rather for writing irc bots*
- [IRClib](http://moepii.sourceforge.net/) *- Neatly organised compact irc library that has support for SSL*

If you're certain you want to write the implementation yourself you can have a look at [this](http://oreilly.com/pub/h/1966).

Comment: I looked at your link. That's for an IRC bot. What I'm trying to do is to create an IRC Client. I'm using that code for output from the server, but I'm not sure what to do for sending chat. Do I just write the chat to server, or do I have to PRIVMSG the whole channel or something?

Comment: @SolomonKim: You want to `PRIVMSG #channel :message here`. [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_Relay_Chat_commands) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [RFC 1459](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1459.html).
It also uses pseudo-BNF, but it is actually easy to understand.

Example:

> #### [4.4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1459.html#section-4.4.1) Private messages
>
> > Command: `PRIVMSG`
> > Parameters: `<receiver>{,<receiver>} <text to be sent>`

> PRIVMSG is used to send private messages between users.  
> is the nickname of the receiver of the message.   can also
> be a list of names or channels separated with commas.

> The  parameter may also me a host mask  (#mask)  or  server
> mask  ($mask).   In  both cases the server will only send the PRIVMSG
> to those who have a server or host matching the mask.  The mask  must
> have at  least  1  (one)  "."  in it and no wildcards following the
> last ".".  This requirement exists to prevent people sending messages
> to  "#*"  or "$*",  which  would  broadcast  to  all  users; from
> experience, this is abused more than used responsibly and properly.
> Wildcards are  the  '*' and  '?'   characters.   This  extension  to
> the PRIVMSG command is only available to Operators.

> Numeric Replies:

> ```
>       ERR_NORECIPIENT                 ERR_NOTEXTTOSEND
>       ERR_CANNOTSENDTOCHAN            ERR_NOTOPLEVEL
>       ERR_WILDTOPLEVEL                ERR_TOOMANYTARGETS
>       ERR_NOSUCHNICK
>       RPL_AWAY
> ```

> Examples:

> ```
> :Angel PRIVMSG Wiz :Hello are you receiving this message ?
> ```

> ;Message from Angel to Wiz.

> ```
> PRIVMSG Angel :yes I'm receiving it !receiving it !
> ```

> Message to Angel.

> ```
> PRIVMSG jto@tolsun.oulu.fi :Hello !
> ```

> Message to a client on server

Note that implementing the IRC protocol can be hard:

- You either have to track all user in the channel and change the client-side view of the users on a `JOIN`, `PART`, `QUIT` `KICK` and `NICK` (and parsing the `NAMES` reply on your join, or ask the server everytime you need a userlist for the `NAMES` in that channel. For a client (which displays the userlist) you have to track it.
- **IRC Colors**: Some people say that it was the worst idea ever implemented in a client (mIRC), but they exist and most clients support them. If you don't, strip them (They start with `\x02` and `\x03`)
- **CTCP** Supporting CTCPs is important:

  - Some servers ask for a `VERSION` reply on connect, some servers even disallow clients without one.
  - `ACTION` ctcps are common and used for the /me command.
  - `DCC` ctcps are common and used for file transfers, establishing direct chat connections, and sending encrypted messages.
- Provide a way for the user to inject abitiary commands. Most clients support the use of `/raw` or `/quote`, some even send every unknown command to the server.
- Provide the common aliases for `/kick`, `/op`...

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell whether you're asking for IRC RFC/Protocol help or actual code since you hanve't supplied any of your current code. When you establish a read stream to a server, output everything to your console. There's a lot to handle, but doing so will make it very clear as to how the protocol works. As for some code along with the protocol:

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());

writer.writeLine("PRIVMSG <destination> :<message>\r\n");
writer.flush();
```

Obviously the above **requires a try-catch**.

Receiving a private message from a user will be in this format:

```
:<sender-nickname>!<sender-ident>@<sender-server> PRIVMSG <your-nickname> :<the-senders-message>
```

Example:

```
:StephenHero!SHPC@google.com PRIVMSG Mast3rPlan :Hello Master Plan!
```

Many IRC server responses commands follow this syntax, [in other words]:

```
:SENDER COMMAND RECIPIENT :MESSAGE
```